# Protobuf helloworld compile error

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers

I checked out the protobuf repository, built with a custom prefix and installed, then copy&pasted the Person example from Google and compiled with `protoc`. That was OK.

But when I include `Person.pb.h` in my CPP file, I get:

```
/home/name/usr/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:53:47: fatal error:
google/protobuf/stubs/type_traits.h: No such file or directory
```

That file was not installed. Is it a bug?

Comment: Well, installing from Ubuntu repository works fine.

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered now?

Comment: @MrLister It's not answered, but workarounded via installation from the repository.